# Resetting theorem counters: \section and (missing) \subsection

Tags: sectioning, numbering, theorems, counters

Suppose I define a new theorem "Theorem" and declare that its counter should be reset whenever the subsection counter is incremented or reset:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
```

At some point in my (article) document I start a new `\section` (say, section 2) without starting a `\subsection`. I expect the first theorem in this section to be numbered with "2.0.1" (which may be considered bad style). However, the theorem is numbered "2.0.2".

Is this "by design" (technically, I didn't start a new `\subsection`) or a bug? Moreover, what would be a proper workaround? (Such a workaround should not involve manually resetting the theorem counter, and it should work for whatever theorem type I may define in addition to "Theorem".)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]

\begin{document}

\section{bla}

\subsection{blubb}

\begin{theorem}
Some text.
\end{theorem}

\subsection{foo}

\begin{theorem}
Some text.
\end{theorem}

\section{bar}

\begin{theorem}
Some text.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: In response to Seamus' comment: The unexpected counter value also occurs with `amsthm` and `ntheorem`.

Comment: That's interesting. Does this persist if you load `amsthm` or `ntheorem`? (I imagine this might be the sort of slight bug that theorem packages might fix...

Comment: @Seamus: No, they do not change that, because technically you could use any counter in the theorem definition, not just one that comes from a section. So the theorem packages have no easy way of figuring out what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In LaTeX, “subcounters” are only reset when the counter is incremented by a `\stepcounter`. They are *not* reset when the counter is changed in any other way (e.g. via `\setcounter` or TeX commands).

The `\section` increments the section counter and thus sets the subsection counter to 0. But this does not reset the theorem counter. Only the next `\subsection` (which increments the subsection counter) resets the theorem counter.

I guess the easiest (or at least safest; see the comments) workaround is to simply add the theorem counter to the reset list for the section counter:

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{theorem}{section}
\makeatother
```

Comment: In other words, the answer to my first question is "by design". What about a workaround like, whenever a "master" counter is incremented, every "slave" counter is *incremented* and only then reset?

Comment: @lockstep: That would require to change the counter reset mechanism of LaTeX: `\def\@stpelt#1{\stepcounter{#1}\global\csname c@#1\endcsname \z@}` (see `texdoc source2e`, page 104). Be aware that this changes that for *all* counters and hence might have unintended side-effects.

Comment: About your "easiest workaround": True, but it would have to be done for every theorem type, so it's not a perfectly automatic solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `\@stpelt` -- I understand that changing its definition shouldn't be done lightly, but this *is* an answer to my second question.

Comment: @lockstep: Alternatively you could add a wrapper around `\newtheorem` that checks what the counter name is and adds the appropriate `\@addtoreset`s.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps more of a motivation to Caramdir's answer, the LaTeX core - [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) - defines a new theorem in **your** usage via [`\newtheorem{<env_name>}{<caption>}[<within>]`](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-20.html). This defines a new counter called `<env_name>` and executes `\@addtoreset{<env_name>}{<within>}` (if the counter `<within>` exists, otherwise LaTeX produces an error). The latter resets the counter `<env_name>` whenever `<within>` is incremented.

Therefore, adding

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{theorem}{section}
\makeatother
```

resets the `theorem` counter whenever you use `\section{...}` as well.

Answer (score 3):

A less esoteric version of Caramdir's solution is through the `chngcntr` package:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\counterwithin*{theorem}{section}
```

The *-version of `\counterwithin` avoids the package being smart and redefine `\thetheorem` as it would do without the `*`

If you want to avoid doing the additional command for each theorem-like environments you define, just abstract the construction:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\newcommand{\newsubsectheorem}[2]{%
  \newtheorem{#1}{#2}[subsection]%
  \counterwithin{#1}{section}}

\newsubsectheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newsubsectheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newsubsectheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
```

If you later change your mind and want to return to a "section-theorem" numbering, just modify accordingly `\newsubsectheorem`.