# Wrong subsections numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I have a weird problem. My subsections are numbered like this:

> Chapter 1: Subsection 1.0.1 Subsection 1.0.2 Subsection 1.0.3
>
> Chapter 2: Subsection 2.0.4 Subsection 2.0.5
>
> ...
>
> Chapter X: Subsection X.0.

I have no idea how to start fixing this error. The only warning I get is:

```
Chapter1.tex(1): Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is    activepdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been       already used, duplicate ignored
Chapter1.tex(26): destination with the same identifier (name{page.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

but I doubt it has anything to do with the problem. 
Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: The level below `\chapter` is `\section`.

Comment: yes exactly this was the issue as mentioned in my comment to the accepted answer :) +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using the sectioning commands `\chapter` (level 0) and `\subsection` (level 2), but not the "in-between" command `\section` (level 1). This is rather uncommon and possibly a misunderstandng on your part.

If you insist on using `\subsection` this way, you have to reset the `subsection` counter manually immediately after the start of a new `\chapter`. See [Resetting theorem counters: \section and (missing) \subsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24822/resetting-theorem-counters-sections-and-missing-subsections) for an explanation.

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla}

\setcounter{subsection}{0}

\subsection{blubb}

\chapter{foo}

\setcounter{subsection}{0}

\subsection{bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: stupid me. I was using \subsection instead of \section :) thank you very much!