# Wrong numeration in LyX Subsubsection

Tags: sectioning, numbering, lyx

I'm typing my lecture notes in one big `.lyx` file, and I use numeration to keep stuff organised in the TOC:

- Numbered Sections for Lectures\Recitations\Tutorials
- Numbered Subsections for Lecture\Recitation\Tutorial parts (e.g. For search algorithms, to distinguish between BFS and DFS)
- Numbered Subsubsections for Lemmas, Theorems, Examples and the etc.

Since I wasn't doing that from the beginning, I've just finished converting what I've already typed, and all the numbers are correct. But, when I begin typing a new Section, when I don't have a Subsection in it, the numeration continues from the last Subsubsection instead of starting over. In other words, this is what happens:

End of Lecture 2:

> 3.3.5 Conclusion

Begining of Lecture 3:

> 4 Lecture number 03 - 07.11.2011
>
> 4.0.6 Lemma:

Screenshot: [image: screenshot illustrating the problem]

How can it be solved, to output:

> 4.0.1 Lemma:

without adding Subsection between the Section and the Subsubsection?
I've tried to do that, and it results:

> 4 Lecture number 03 - 07.11.2011
>
> 4.1 Dummytext
>
> 4.1.1 Lemma:

But it don't need the Subsection there...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official stackexchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: CTRL+G). This ensures that all images are always accessible and do not expire. (As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the ! in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the ! to turn it into an image again.)

Comment: Re: Wrong numbering persists in LyX editor: It would be best to repost this as a fresh question. Follow-up questions like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Comment: @lockstep [Done](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39303/wrong-numbering-persists-in-lyx-editor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding a "Dummytext" subsection, you have to add the following ERT ("Evil Red Text", i.e., LaTeX code) at the same place in your document:

```
\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}
```

See [Resetting theorem counters: \section and (missing) \subsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24822/resetting-theorem-counters-sections-and-missing-subsections) for some background information.

Comment: Thank you! It works the way I wanted it! Would you suggest adding such ERT every time I begin a new Section or should I just "patch" the document when this problem occures?

Comment: Because "missing" subsections before subsubsections aren't too common, I'd rather go for the second approach.

Comment: I think I was in a hurry, but now I see that while in the pdf output, the numbering is correct, in the LyX editor, I still see the wrong numbering. Is there a way to fix it there as well?

Comment: @Khaloymes Sorry, I don't know enough about LyX to answer this.