# Wrong numbering persists in LyX

Tags: sectioning, numbering, lyx

When I try to organise my notes using Section\Subsection\Subsubsection numeration, I keep getting the wrong numbers in the editor:

[image: PDF output and the origial text side by side]

Previously, [I've got help finding the solution to fix this problem in my PDF output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39288/wrong-numeration-in-lyx-subsubsection).

Now I want to have a correct output in the editor as well. Is there a way to fix it from within LyX document\editor settings?

Comment: I rolled back to revision 2 because Thorsten's edit (that was suggested before rev 2, but accepted after it) effectively was a rollback of rev 2, which was more extensive.

Comment: Without a minimal example it's quite difficult to tell something

Comment: Would removing all `.aux` or temp files and then recompiling help in any?