# Counter linked to section and subsection

Tags: counters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resetting theorem counters: \sections and (missing) \subsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24822/resetting-theorem-counters-sections-and-missing-subsections)

I create a new counter as follow :

```
\newcounter{question}[section]
```

Thus at each new section `thequestion` is set to 1. If I do the following :

```
\newcounter{question}[subection]
```

`thequestion` is not set to 1 when a new section begin (without subsection). Is it possible to link a counter to both section and subsection ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `chngcntr` package, and then write

`\counterwithin{question}{subsection}` or `section`, the effect should be the same.

Otherwise, you can define the reset yourself

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{question}{subsection}
\makeatother
```

Comment: `@addtoreset` work perfectly, thanks