# Theorem numbering error

Tags: sectioning, numbering, theorems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resetting theorem counters: \sections and (missing) \subsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24822/resetting-theorem-counters-sections-and-missing-subsections)

I have the following in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{citesort}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\textheight=22.5truecm
\textwidth=15.5truecm
\parindent=12pt \parskip=7pt
\hoffset -2cm
\voffset -1cm
\pretolerance=1000
\newtheorem{tetel}{Tétel}[subsection]
```

However the theorems in section 3 before the first subsection are numbered starting from 4 as the screenshot shows:

[image: incorrect numbering]

Never before have I seen this problem. The numbering worked perfectly in every section in every document so far. What could cause this behavior?

Comment: If you number theorems by subsections, each of them must appear after a `\subsection` command. It's this command that resets to zero the `tete` counter. How should that theorem be numbered?

Comment: @egreg I wanted it to be 3.0.1. I can see now that the counter was not reset from the previous section. I guess I will have to do that manually.

Comment: @scineram Look at the linked question, it should solve your problem. If it doesn't, please state here why.

Comment: @egreg It does, just the search didn't throw that up. Should I delete this duplicate?

Comment: @scineram No, don't; it can be useful for searches. The important thing is that the reference to the other question is clear (and it will be when officially closed).