# \subsubsubsection count not reset when starting a new section, subsection, etc

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, subdividing

I am trying to use subsubsubsection on my report, and I using a code that [was given on this website](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60212/).

On below my MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,french]{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

\newcounter{subsubsubsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}} % optional; useful if paragraphs are to be numbered

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{6}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\pagebreak

\section{test}
\subsubsubsection{test11}
\subsubsubsection{test12}
\subsubsubsection{test13}

\section{test2}
\subsubsubsection{test21}
\subsubsubsection{test22}
\subsubsubsection{test23}

\end{document}
```

As you will notice,  the subsubsubsection is not reset between these 2 sections.

[image: How can I fix it please ?]

How can I fix it please ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I do not know about titlesec new sections, but it should read  `\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]` since this triggers the resetting of the counter a level below subsubsection.

Comment: By the way, I am not sure about adding another section level enables readability of such a document. I never needed paragraphs etc., but this is a matter of taste and not a dogma.

Comment: @Christian : I tried your proposal, but the counting wasn't reset neither. Concerning the readability, I understand your point, but I actually need to use these \subsubsubsections anyway. I am not looking for another way for doing it, only looking on a way to fix my issue. Thank you anyway for trying to help me.

Comment: You do not need to define a subsubsubsection counter, LaTeX `report` class already has two more levels of section heading defined below subsubsection, namely `paragraph` and `subparagraph` these are already set up to reset and have correct level in the table of contents etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `subsubsubsection` counter is reset at `subsubsection`. In your example the `subsubsection` counter never changed. (It remains always at zero.)

(More precisely, the reset command is only triggered when `\stepcounter` or `\refstepcounter` is called on the parent counter. As no `\subsubsection` command was ever issued, the counter is never step-increased, and the reset command never called.)

You can see the problem even without defining your own new section level. If you compile the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\subsubsection{test2}
\section{test3}
\subsubsection{test4}
\subsection{test 5}
\subsubsection{test6}
\end{document}
```

You will see that `test2` is labeled `1.0.1` and `test4` is labeled `2.0.2`. But once you increment the `subsection` counter (when I put in `test 5`), the counter now behaves properly: `test6` is `2.1.1`.

This doesn't happen just with sectioning commands, by the way. If you use the `\numberwithin` command from the AMS packages to set the level for equations, or use the `amsthm` commands to tie theorem numbering to section levels, you should never tie the resetting to a counter that cannot be reliably incremented.

A possible work-around is given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24822/resetting-theorem-counters-section-and-missing-subsection): in your preamble add

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{subsubsubsection}{section}
\@addtoreset{subsubsubsection}{subsection}
\makeatother
```

this will make increasing sections and subsections both also trigger the reset code.

Comment: thank you very much for these very clear explanations. That solved my issue. Have a nice day!