# subsubsections numbering does not restart

Tags: sectioning

I have a list of sections in my document...

```
\section{animals}
\section{places}
```

etc..

I need to organize the contents within each section.
To do this I decided to use subsubsections instead of subsections in order to save some space...

```
\section{animals}
\subsubsection{cats}
\subsubsection{dogs}
\section{places}
\subsubsection{muntains}
\subsubsection{lakes}
```

My problem is that the numbering of the subsubsections does not restart with the new section...how do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: full minimal example please? We cannot compile this as we do not know the preamble or which documentclass you are using. BTW: why subsubsection right after a section?

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161442. Note that the team have very recently fixed this in LaTeX and it will work properly in the upcoming release!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/5764)

Comment: @Werner That's the opposite concept, no?

Comment: Auch! my document is super messy...I will try to replicate the behaviour using a new one...

Comment: @JosephWright: It deals with both from what I read...

Comment: Note that using `\subsubsection` because of the default styling can be made to work but it is entirely the wrong thing to do, it messes up the logical structure of the document, will mess up the table of contents (without further workarounds) the code that specifies the fonts and spacing for \subsection in article class is exactly one line long: you can change it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\preto{\section}{\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}}
\begin{document}
  \section{animals}
  \subsubsection{cats}
  \subsubsection{dogs}
  \section{places}
  \subsubsection{muntains}
  \subsubsection{lakes}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesection.\Numberstring{subsubsection}}
\preto{\section}{\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}}
\begin{document}
  \section{animals}
  \subsubsection{cats}
  \subsubsection{dogs}
  \section{places}
  \subsubsection{muntains}
  \subsubsection{lakes}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Super! It works perfectly

Comment: @gabboshow add \tableofcontents :-)

Comment: Is it possible to change in the subsubsections the numbers in letters?

Comment: @gabboshow Please see the update. Try `\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\Numberstring{section}.\Numberstring{subsubsection}}` too if you like.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than distort the document markup, you can just specify that subsections are styled like subsubsections, just copying the relevant line from `article.cls`

```
\documentclass{article}

% copy from subsubsection
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
  \section{animals}
  \subsection{cats}
  \subsection{dogs}
  \section{places}
  \subsection{muntains}
  \subsection{lakes}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You also can do that with the `chngcntr` package and its `counterwithin` command. If you want the label be typed as, say,  **`1`** rather than **`1.1`**, use `\counterwithin*`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsproc

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin{subsubsection}{section}
\begin{document}

\section{animals}
\subsubsection{cats}
\subsubsection{dogs}
\section{places}
\subsubsection{mountains}
\subsubsection{lakes}

\end{document}
```

[image]