# Definition counter resetting on new section

Tags: sectioning, numbering, theorems, counters, definition

I encountered this behavior from LaTex: last definition from section 2.1 was labeled (correctly) as 2.1.8. Then, the first definition of the next section was 2.2.9. I would like it to be 2.2.1 (don't know the standards but that makes much more sense to me). I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24822/resetting-theorem-counters-section-and-missing-subsection) which is kinda relevant but works with theorems and not definitions.

The only commands(I think) that modify somehow the definitions are:

`\newtheorem{definition}{MyDef}`

`\renewcommand{\thedefinition}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{definition}}`

So, how do I change it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A simple `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]` should work as expected and number youd definitions as follows: "chapter.section.definition"  while the definition counter starts from 1 with every new section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]` should result in the expected output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter}
\section{first section}

\begin{definition}
first definition in first section
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
second definition in first section
\end{definition}

\section{second section}

\begin{definition}
first definition in second section
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Simple and effective.